# EF Core 3.1 Intermediate Projection VS Iterating Result to Set Additional Property

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, ef-core-3.1

Say I have an entity model..

```
public class MyEntity
{
  public DateTime TransactionDate {get; set;}
  public decimal TotalSales {get; set;}
  public long TotalPurchases {get; set;}
}
```

and I am populating a list of this entity from a SQLServer DB pretty easily for a range of transaction date.

```
var results = await _dbContext.StoresDailyTransactions
    .Where(t => t.TransactionDate > = rangeStartDate && t.TransactionDate <= rangeEndDate)
    .GroupBy(o => o.TransactionDate)
    .Select(g => new MyEntity
    {
        TransactionDate = g.Key,
        TotalSales = g.Sum(c => c.Sales),
        TotalPurchases = g.Sum(c => c.Purchases),
    })
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Now there is a need to add the AverageSale to the entity...

```
public class MyEntity
{
  public DateTime TransactionDate {get; set;}
  public decimal TotalSales {get; set;}
  public long TotalPurchases {get; set;}
  public decimal AverageSale {get; set;}
}
```

Which is easy enough because I have the values already selected in my query just need to calculate the average and assign it to the new AverageSale property....

```
  AverageSale = TotalSales / TotalPurchases
```

I have considered doing this 2 different ways.

1) Just iterate my existing list of results being produced before and set the new property before returning the results.

```
  foreach(MyEntity currentEntity in results)
  {
    currentEntity.AverageSales = currentEntity.TotalSales / currentEntity.TotalPurchases;
  }
```

2) Do everything in the linq statement by selecting to an intermediate anon projection and then a final projection to MyEntity with the new AverageSale.

```
var results = await _dbContext.StoresDailyTransactions
    .Where(t => t.TransactionDate > = rangeStartDate && t.TransactionDate <= rangeEndDate)
    .GroupBy(o => o.TransactionDate)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        TransactionDate = g.Key,
        TotalSales = g.Sum(c => c.Sales),
        TotalPurchases = g.Sum(c => c.Purchases),
    })
    .Select(a => new
    {
        TransactionDate = a.TransactionDate,
        TotalSales = a.TotalSales,
        TotalPurchases = a.TotalPurchases,
        AverageSale = a.TotalSales / a.TotalPurchases,
    })
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .ToListAsync();
```

The first option is very easy to read and understand what is happening but it has kinda has a smell about it and it seems like it could be easily broken by a careless developer because it is separate from everything else... e.g. lost in merge conflict, accidentally deleted or commented out.

The second option really seems less error-prone because either it all just works or it doesn't. Though it is seems less readable and takes a second to catch why it is being projected by two select statements back to back.

Is there anything else that makes one of these objectively better such as performance etc or maybe even a better way which I haven't considered?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that and it is an interesting solution except there is actually an AverageSale column in the table. The column represents the average sale for the single store per day's transactions and this needs to be AverageSale of a group of stores (think district) per day for reporting purposes. Sorry I didn't think that detail was relevant and so simplified it out of the question. Also there is a strict standard at my company that data models can't contain logic which kinda leaves this possibility out as well.

Comment: Are you saying that you are projecting query result to real entity model having its own table? This sounds like code smell, `MyEntity` should really be DTO / ViewModel

Comment: It is a view in the DB. There is a column named AverageSale in the View already. The strait results of the view are being reported as an DTO of the View itself. I am producing a slimmed down representation of the the view with a different DTO and the caveat that the AverageSale in my result is for a grouping of stores and not an individual store on a single date like the AverageSale represents in the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSales { get; set; }
    public long TotalPurchases { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageSale => this.TotalSales / this.TotalPurchases;
}
```

Your query then stays the same:

```
var results = await _dbContext.StoresDailyTransactions
                              .Where(t => t.TransactionDate >= rangeStartDate 
                                     && t.TransactionDate <= rangeEndDate)
                              .GroupBy(o => o.TransactionDate)
                              .Select(g => new MyEntity
                              {
                                  TransactionDate = g.Key,
                                  TotalSales = g.Sum(c => c.Sales),
                                  TotalPurchases = g.Sum(c => c.Purchases),
                              })
                              .DefaultIfEmpty()
                              .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that and it is an interesting solution except there is actually an AverageSale column in the table. The column represents the average sale for the single store per day's transactions and this needs to be AverageSale of a group of stores (think district) per day for reporting purposes. Sorry I didn't think that detail was relevant and so simplified it out of the question. Also there is a strict standard at my company that data models can't contain logic which kinda leaves this possibility out as well.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your statement. `MyEntity` is a DTO/ViewModel, not an actual DB entity as per @IvanStoev comment above, correct?.

Comment: It is just a DTO that is mapped to an API model returned to the UI. Didn't mean to muddy the waters by calling it MyEntity.